# Splitting a list into two lists each containing a range of elements from the initial one

Tags: list-manipulation

If I had a list of let's say 20 elements, how could I split it into two separate lists that contain every other 5 elements of the initial list?

For example:

```
list={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}
function[list]
(*
{1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,15}
{6,7,8,9,10,16,17,18,19,20}
*)
```

Follow-up question:

Thanks to the numerous answers! Is there a way to revert this process? Say we start from two lists and I would like to end up with the `list`above:

```
list1={1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,15}
list2={6,7,8,9,10,16,17,18,19,20}
function[list1,list2]
(*
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}
*)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]
f1[lst_, k_] := Join @@ Partition[lst[[# ;;]], k, 2 k, 1, {}] & /@ {1, k + 1}

{list1, list2} = f1[list, 5]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
>   {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}}

An alternative way using the (still undocumented) 6th argument of `Partition`:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]
f2[lst_, k_] := Partition[Drop[lst, #], k, 2 k, 1, {}, Sequence] & /@ {0, k}

{list1, list2} = f2[list, 5]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
>   {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}}

**Update:** To revert the process:

```
ClearAll[fb]
fb[lst1_, lst2_, k_] := Join @@ Riffle @@ (Partition[#, k, k, 1, {}] & /@ {lst1, lst2})

fb[list1, list2, 5]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}

Comment: Is there a way to revert this process? Please see the updated question.

Comment: @xabdax, please see the update.

Comment: Thanks. It does not seem to be working for longer lists, length 40 for instance.

Comment: @xabdax, please see the new version of the update.

Answer (score 4):

```
Flatten /@ {#[[1 ;; ;; 2]], #[[2 ;; ;; 2]]} &@Partition[list, 5]
```

gives desired

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
function = Flatten[Transpose[Fold[Partition, #, {5, 2}]], {{1}, {2, 3}}] &;
```

If the length of the input is not a multiple of `10`, it will effectively cut off the remainder at the end.

Answer (score 1):

**Using `UpTo`:** (with a list containing 23 elements)

```
list = Range[23];

Clear[chunk, unchunk];
chunk[k_List, n_ /; n ∈ PositiveIntegers] := 
 Flatten /@ {#[[1 ;; ;; 2]], #[[2 ;; ;; 2]]} &@Partition[k, UpTo[n]]

unchunk[{a_List, b_List}, n_ /; n ∈ PositiveIntegers] :=
 Catenate@Riffle[Partition[a, UpTo[n]], Partition[b, UpTo[n]]]
```

---

*Usage:*

```
Echo@unchunk[Echo@chunk[list, 5], 5];
```

[image]