# Cut a list into two sublists containing alternating chunks?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

Consider a list such as

```
list=Range[20]
```

> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 }

I would like to have a function (e.g. `fun[list_,chunks_]`) that would cut it into two different lists, containing equal sized alternating chunks of the original list. For example:

```
{list1,list2}=fun[list,5];
list1
list2
```

> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }
>
> { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 }

Is there a function like that in mathematica? Or maybe one can implement it conveniently?

EDIT:

Here is my rough and ugly abomination

```
fun[list_, chunk_] := Block[{prt},
  If[! IntegerQ[Length[list]/chunk], Return["GTFO!:P"];];
  prt = Partition[list, chunk];
  {Flatten@prt[[1 ;; ;; 2]], Flatten@prt[[2 ;; ;; 2]]}
  ]
```

Certainly this should work much more elegantly/efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a bit simpler:

```
fun[list_,chunk_]:=
Flatten[Partition[list,chunk][[#;;;;2]]]&/@{1,2}
```

Comment: See also: [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/204151/731).